# Excel VBA If cell.Value="word 1" Then

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to keep only the values not the formulas in the cells if the cell is="Yes"
Here is my code:

```
Sub Fixed()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("Q4799:Q4825")
On Error Resume Next
If cell.Value = "Yes" Then

cell.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
     :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

I ran it for cells that are currently some formulas they are like this:

```
=INDEX(Copy!B:B,MATCH(Manifest!A4800,Copy!A:A,0))
```

And it look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaSFt.png)
However, It seems to be performing actions regardless what that cell value is. So, it is currently doing things for every cells from Q4799:Q4825 even if it is not "Yes".

How can I fix it?

Comment: Change the whole copy paste part to cell.value = cell.value

Comment: Move activeworkbook.save to outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten as,

```
Sub Fixed()

    Dim cell As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each cell In Range("Q4799:Q4825")
        If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Alternate for all text based (non-numerical, non-boolean, non-error) values returned from a formula.

```
Sub Fixed()

    with Range("Q4799:Q4825").specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlTextValues)
        .Value = .Value
    end with

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't let the code save the worksheet. If the user forgets to save the code can be run again but if the code shouldn't have been run the damage is permanent. Excel's "natural" safety valve is to close the workbook without saving and get back the original state on re-opening. The `Save` command in the code disables the emergency exit.

Comment: Thank you SO much!